# Google Chrome browser notification history

Tags: chrome, notification

Is there a way/place where to see the notification history of the Google Chrome browser?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1035042/399064

Comment: @Hex I've read it while searching a solution before posting. I'm on linux not Mac. I've enabled the _native notifications_ option anyway. And now... ?

Comment: Have you tried [PushBullet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pushbullet.android&referrer=utm_source%3Dpushbullet.com)? I think it should be doing what you want, if I understand your question correctly. And it does not matter whether you are on Linux or Mac, as it is a browser plugin.

Comment: it worked!!!!! Push Bullet logs Chrome notification history with ease!!!

Comment: I've installed the Pushbullet Chrome extension, and it doesn't seem to show any of the several test notifications I've triggered. To be clear, is this on PC or mobile?